# panel is not working inside the div - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am implementing the vertical toggle panel but it is not getting toggled after the click on + icon, I have pasted entire code. 
Code: Below is entire code:

find this comment in the Technical Sheet section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Projects Details</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="ppcr.js"></h:outputScript>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="ppcr.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.subMenu').smint({
                'scrollSpeed' : 1000
            });
        });

    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);">

    <div class="header">
        <h:graphicImage style="vertical-align: middle" value="resources/images/logoMainShort.gif" />
        <b style="vertical-align: top;"> Quotation Tool</b>
    </div>

    <div style="line-height: 25px;margin: 0px 6px 0px 6px;">
        <h:form>     
            <div class="navigation">
                <h:outputLink value="projects.xhtml">
                    <h:outputText value="PROJECTS" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;"></h:outputText>
                </h:outputLink>
                <h:outputLink value="masterData.xhtml">
                    <b style="padding-left: 20px;">
                        <h:outputText 
                            value="MASTER DATA"
                            style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </b>
                </h:outputLink>
            </div>      
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <div class= "background">
        <div class="test" style="padding-top: 10px">Ford_V408_2015_PPCR01</div>
        <!-- <div class="wrap"> -->
        <div class="subMenu" style="margin-left: 1px">
            <a href="#" style="width: 88%;" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">List To Quote</a>
        </div>
        <div class="subMenu" style="margin-left: 22%">
            <a href="#" style="width: 88%;" id="s2" class="subNavBtn">AVO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="subMenu" style="margin-left: 43.8%">
            <a href="#" style="width: 88%;" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Technical Sheet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="subMenu" style="margin-left: 65%">
            <a href="#" style="width: 88%;" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Geometry</a>
        </div>

        <h:form id="testForm">  
            <div class="innersection">
                <div class="section s5">
                    <div class="heading"> 
                        <h:outputText value="Project information" /> 
                    </div>

                    <p:panelGrid 
                        style="margin:5px 0px 15px 0px; 
                        width:100%"
                        styleClass="panelgrid">

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column style="border:white" styleClass="columnA">Brand Group</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="Ford" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Model (Car Name) </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="Ford Mondeo" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Annual Model Volume </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="25 000" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Lifetime</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="3 years" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Brand</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="Ford" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Project Code</p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <h:commandLink value="FORD_V408_2015" action="/projectDetails.xhtml" target="_blank"
                                   style="cursor:pointer;font-style: normal; font-family: Arial;color:#0000ff;font-size:13px;text-decoration: underline;"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Reason to quote</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="New Car" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Peak Volume</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="25 000" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <div class="heading"> 
                        <h:outputText value="PPCR general information" /> 
                    </div>

                    <p:panelGrid
                        id="addText"  
                        style="margin:5px 0px 15px 0px; width:100%"
                        styleClass="panelgrid">

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Part Type</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="WS" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">PPCR Date</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="25/10/2013" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA"  style="width:14%;">Development Step</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedStepsValue}" style="width:280px;" >
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.stepsValue}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>     
                        </p:row>    

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Family</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:outputText value="Laminated  " />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Reply Date</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:inputText value="04/11/2013" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Reason for<br/> update</p:column>
                            <p:column rowspan="3" styleClass="columnB">
                                <p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="42" autoResize="false" />
                            </p:column>                             
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA">Market</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                            <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedMarketValue}" style="width:140px;" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.marketValue}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:14%;">Reference PPCR</p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                                <h:inputText size="16"/>
                            </p:column> 
                            <p:column/>     
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column 
                                style="font-style: normal; font-family:Arial;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;width:15%;color: #333333;
                                    text-align: right;">
                                    Document Hyperlink
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column colspan="3">
                                <h:inputText size="51"/>
                                <p:commandLink>
                                    <p:graphicImage 
                                        style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;position: middle;border: none; WIDTH:15px; HEIGHT:15px;" 
                                        value="resources/images/attach.png"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </p:column> 
                            <p:column/>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="4"/>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="vertical-align:top;">Industrialization Manager</p:column>           
                            <p:column  styleClass="columnB" style="width:15%" >
                            <ui:repeat var="input" value="#{bean.inputTexts}">
                                 <p:inputText size="18" value="#{inputTexts}" style="margin-bottom:2px;"/>
                            </ui:repeat>

                             <b style="padding:0px 0px 0px 18px">
                                 <p:commandButton 
                                     value="Add Manager"
                                     actionListener="#{bean.addInput}"
                                     update="addText"  
                                      style=" margin-bottom:10px;width:auto;height:28px;font-style: normal; font-family:Arial;font-size: 13px;
                                            color: #000000;text-align:center;font-weight: normal;text-decoration:none;cursor: pointer "/>
                            </b> 
                            </p:column> 
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <div class="heading"> 
                        <h:outputText value="Packaging" /> 
                    </div>

                    <p:panelGrid 
                          styleClass="panelgrid"
                          style="margin:5px 0px 15px 0px; width:100%;" >

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnC" style="width:25%">Customer Packaging
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnC" style="width:25%">AGC Container
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnC" style="width:25%">OEM
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnC" style="width:25%; text-align:center;">ARG
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>

                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <div class="heading"> 
                        <h:outputText value="Logistics" /> 
                    </div>

                    <p:panelGrid 
                           id="logistics"
                           styleClass="panelgrid" 
                           style="margin:5px 0px 15px 0px; width:100%;" >

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="6" />
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:15%;vertical-align:top;">Shipping location </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB" >
                             <ui:repeat var="input" value="#{bean.inputLocation}">
                                <p:inputText  value="#{inputLocation}" style="margin-bottom:2px;"/>
                             </ui:repeat>   
                                <p:commandButton 
                                    value="Add Location"
                                    actionListener="#{bean.addLocation}"
                                    update="logistics" 
                                    style=" margin-bottom:10px;width:auto;height:28px;font-style: normal; font-family:Arial;
                                        font-size: 13px;color: #000000;text-align:center;font-weight: normal;text-decoration:none;cursor: pointer "/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:15%; vertical-align:top; ">Incoterm </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB">
                            <ui:repeat var="input" value="#{bean.inputIncoterm}">  
                                 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedIncotermValue}" style="width:140px;margin-bottom:6px" >
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.incotermValue}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </ui:repeat>    

                                <!-- <b style="margin: 0px 30px 20px 0px;">  -->
                                    <p:commandButton 
                                        value="Add Incoterm"
                                        actionListener="#{bean.addIncoterm}"
                                        update="logistics" 
                                        style=" margin-bottom:10px;width:auto;height:28px;font-style: normal; font-family:Arial;font-size: 13px;
                                            color: #000000;text-align:center;font-weight: normal;text-decoration:none;cursor: pointer "/>
                                <!-- </b> -->           
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnA" style="width:15% ;vertical-align:top;" >Just in sequence </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="columnB" style="width:20%;vertical-align:top;">
                                <h:selectOneMenu    value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedSequenceValue}" style="width:100px;" >
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.sequenceValue}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                <h:outputText 
                                       value="per day" 
                                       style="margin-left:5px;font-style: normal; font-family:Arial; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;color:#999999;font-size: 13px;"/>
                            </p:column> 
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="8" />
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </div>

                <div class="section s1">
                    Removed code fron this section
                </div>

                <div class="section s2">
                    <h1>AVO</h1>
                </div>

                <!-- PPCR: Technical Section -->

                <div class="section s3">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h:outputText value="Technical Sheet" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="border">
                        <p:panelGrid style="margin:5px 0px 15px 0px; width:100%"    
                          styleClass="panelgrid"> 

                           <p:row>
                               <p:column colspan="2"/>
                           </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column  styleClass="columnB" style="width:30%">
                                   <h:commandLink action="/pdfFileUpload.xhtml" target="options:height=200, width=300">
                                     <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/upload.png" 
                                         style="vertical-align: middle; position: middle;border: none;"/>
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </p:column>
                            <!-- Panel is not working -->   
                                <p:column rowspan="11" style="vertical-align:top">
                                    <p:panel header="Size" toggleable="true" rendered="true"
                                        toggleOrientation="vertical">
                                        <h:outputText value="Test" />
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:column>
                            <!-- Panel is not working -->   
                            </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                               <p:column />
                            </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                               <p:column />
                            </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:outputText 
                                  value="Manufacuring Control Method"
                                  style="color:#164990;font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;" />
                             </p:column>
                             </p:row>   

                             <p:row>  
                               <p:column >
                                 <h:outputText value="Check fixt. position" styleClass="columnD"/>
                                 <h:selectOneMenu  
                                       value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedMarketValue}" 
                                       style="width:200px;font-style: normal;font-family: Arial;FONT-WEIGHT: 400;font-size: 13px;text-align: left;color: #333333;
                                              margin-left: 15px;" >
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.marketValue}" />
                                  </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row>

                            <p:row>  
                               <p:column >
                                 <h:outputText value="Check fixt. concept" styleClass="columnD"/>
                                 <h:selectOneMenu  
                                      value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedMarketValue}" 
                                      style="width:200px;font-style: normal;font-family: Arial;FONT-WEIGHT: 400;font-size: 13px;text-align: left;color: #333333;
                                              margin-left: 15px;" >
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.marketValue}" />
                                  </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row>

                            <p:row>  
                               <p:column >
                                 <h:outputText value="Spacers" styleClass="columnD" style="margin-left:21%"/>
                                 <h:selectOneMenu  
                                    value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedMarketValue}" 
                                     style="width:200px;font-style: normal;font-family: Arial;FONT-WEIGHT: 400;font-size: 13px;text-align: left;color: #333333;
                                              margin-left: 15px;" >
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.marketValue}" />
                                  </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row>

                            <p:row>  
                               <p:column >
                                 <h:outputText value="Stoppers" styleClass="columnD" style="margin-left:20%"/>
                                 <h:selectOneMenu  
                                    value="#{ppcrGeneral.selectedMarketValue}" 
                                    style="width:200px;font-style: normal;font-family: Arial;FONT-WEIGHT: 400;font-size: 13px;text-align: left;color: #333333;
                                              margin-left: 15px;" >
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{ppcrGeneral.marketValue}" />
                                  </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column> 
                            </p:row>

                            <p:row>
                               <p:column colspan="2"/>
                           </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                               <p:column colspan="2"/>
                           </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                      <!-- PPCR: Technical Section Ends -->


                <div class="section s4">
                    <h1>Geometry</h1>
                    <br class="clear"></br>
                </div>
            </div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push([ '_setAccount', 'UA-9804757-1' ]);
    _gaq.push([ '_trackPageview' ]);
  (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'
    : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
</h:form>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats JSF and PF version do you use. The provided code works for me under PF 3.5 + Mojarra 2.1.6

Comment: I am using PF 3.4 + mojarra 2.2.0, above code is also working fine for me on individual page but when I am putting it my complete code then panel toggle is not working. Even if including the individual working page inside the main page <ui:include src="test.xhtml"/> then also its not working.

Comment: problem would be your "complete code."  there's something interfering with PF's jquery maybe.  try slowly adding in parts of your "complete code" until it breaks then you know what's causing it. you could also try giving your PF panel an ID in the event behind the scenes an ID on the component to toggle helps resolve ambiguities with jquery.

Comment: Added only  <p:panel header="Size" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="vertical">
       <h:outputText value="Test" />
    </p:panel> inside the first div and its Not working.

Comment: please post the whole (minimal) example of your code that is not working (edit your question and leave a comment)

Comment: Thank you stg, I have added then entire code. Please find the comment <!-- Panel is not working -->

Answer (score 0):

probably that's because of jquery ,if you include jquery in your page many of primefaces components doesn't work correctly,
replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with :

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```